# Minimal conditions on random vector $X \in R^n$ to ensure that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\sup_{\|w\|_p = 1}\sup_{u \in \mathbb R}\mathbb P(|X'w-u| \le t)=0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Let $X$ be a random variable on $\mathbb R^n$ and let $S_p^n := \{w \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|w\|_p = 1\}$ be the unit-sphere w.r.t to the $\ell_p$-norm in $\mathbb R^n$. We will be particularly interested in the case $p \in \{1,2\}$. For any $w \in B_p^n$ and $t \ge 0$, let
$$
L(X'w,t):= \sup_{u \in \mathbb R}\mathbb P(|X' w - u| \le t).
$$
be the *Lévy concentration function* of the random variable $X' w$. Finally, define
$$
 L(S_p^n,t) := \sup_{w \in S_p^n} L(X'w,t).
$$

> **Question.** *Under what minimal assumptions on $X$ is it true that $\lim_{t \to 0^+} L(S_p^n, t) \to 0 $ ?*

For example, does it suffice to assume that

- $X$ has density which is sufficiently smooth (e.g continuous) ?
- What if we simply assume that the distribution of $X$ is atomless ?

---

### Some solved cases

- **(1) Bounded Radon transform of density of $X$.**
  Suppose there exists a positive constant $b$ such that for every $w \in B_p^n$, the random variable $X'w$ has density bounded by $b$. Then,
  $$
  L(S_p^n,t) = \sup_{w \in S_p^n}\sup_{u \in \mathbb R}\mathbb P(|X'w-u| \le t) \le b\cdot 2t = 2bt \to 0.
  $$
  For example, this is the case when the distribution of $X$ is a mixture of multivariate Gaussians $\sum_k\pi_kN(\mu_k,\Sigma_k)$; in this case each $X'w$ has distribution $\sum_k \pi_k N(\mu_k'w,w'\Sigma_k w)$, and the condition clearly holds with $b=1$.
  Finally, note that if $f$ is the density of $X$, then the density $\rho_w$ of $X'w$ evaluated at a point $c$ is nothing but the Radon transform $R[f]$ of $f$ w.r.t the hyperplane $H_{w,c} := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x'w = c\}$. Thus, the assumption that $\sup_{w \in S_p^n}\|\rho_w\|_\infty \le b$, is really reminiscent of demanding that $R[f] \in L^\infty$. So the question now is, under what minimal conditions if the Radon transform of a density function bounded ?
- **(2) $X$ is an transformation of log-concave random vector.** C

---

onsider the scenario where  $X \overset{D}{=}AZ + \mu$, where $A$ is a deterministic $m \times n$ matrix, $\mu$ is a determistic vector in $\mathbb R^m$, and $Z$ is random variable which is isotropic, log-concave, whose coordinates are $b$-subGaussian, then thanks to Grigoris Paouris' [Small Ball Probability Estimates for Log-Concave Measures](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2012-364-01/S0002-9947-2011-05411-5/S0002-9947-2011-05411-5.pdf), we know that
$$
L(X'w,t) = L((Aw)'X,t) \le (t/\|Aw\|_2)^{(c/b)^2},\text{ for sufficiently small }t
$$
where $c$ is an absolute positive constant. Thus, if $A$ is non-degenerate in the sense that $\kappa_p(A) := \inf_{w \in S_p^n} \|Aw\|_2 \ge 1/C >  0$, then

$$
L(S_p^n,t) \le (t/\kappa_{p}(A))^{(c/b)^2} = (Ct)^{(c/b)^2} \to 0.
$$

Comment: Any reason why this question has been downvoted without comment ?

Comment: how about using the maximal operator estimate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function) for the density f of X: $$|\{u \ : \ Proba(|X-u|<t) >t \alpha\}| \leq |\{u \ : \ (Mf)(u) > \alpha\}| \leq \frac{c}{\alpha}\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} |f|$$
to get that in in the tail ends: |u|>R for some fixed R, we have P(|X-u|<t) <t and in |u|<R we might have P(|X-u|<t) >t but because the region is bounded, we can try to apply extreme value theorem?

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thanks for bringing up Littlewood max function. However, I don't quite see how one would use this to argue about individual $u$'s that occur in the definition $L(X'w,t):=\sup_{u \in \mathbb R}\mathbb P(|X'w-u| \le t)$. Clear details would be appreciated.

Comment: Also note that my question is sufficient conditions on $X$ to ensure that $L(S_p^n,t) \to 0$ in the limit $t\to 0^+$. So passing via Hardy-Littlewood, in the ideal case what would you expect such a condition on the density of $f$ to look like ?

Answer (score 2):

In Hengartner, W. and Theodorescu, R. (1973). Concentration Functions. Academic Press, New York. MR033144

they study the continuity properties and when the concentration function is zero even for the multivariate case in THEOREM 1.7.4..

The main idea goes through showing that the maximum is attained for each $t>0$ and so as $t\to 0$, the concentration function goes to zero.

The article ["Maximal Inequalities and Some Applications"](https://www.motapa.de/open/schilling-kuehn-mmax-arxiv.pdf) has many other references too.

Even with the extra supremum over the sphere, the same argument should work i.e. for each $t>0$ attaining attaining the supremum and using continuity of $X'$.

Some details. Let $f(x,t):=P(|X-x|\leq t)$. Since the set $S_{t}:=\{f(x,t):x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\}$ is bounded, the supremum $L_{t}=\sup_{x}f(x,t)$ is finite i.e. there are sequences  $\epsilon_{n}\to 0, y_{n}=f(x_{n},t)\in S_{t}$ such that

$$L_{t}-\epsilon_{n}\leq f(x_{n},t)\leq L_{t}.$$

So by boundedness of $y_{n}:=f(x_{n},t)\in [0,1]$, we can apply Bolzano-Weirstrass and continuity to get subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x^{*}_{t}$ and

$$L_{t}\leq f(x^{*}_{t},t)\leq L_{t}\Rightarrow L_{t}=f(x^{*}_{t},t).$$

From here we simply use continuity in $t$-variable to get limit zero.

Comment: Thanks for the input (upvoted). Unfortunately, the linked book is not accessible. In particular, I don't have access to the statement of **Theorem 1.7.4** (which you referenced), and so I can't tell if it provides any insight on the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Much clearer now. I see how your core argument goes through, but there are still a few of issues. First, "continuity in $t$-variable" is not for free. This will only hold if, for every $w$, the random variable $X'w$ has density. For this to hold, it is sufficient to assume that the random vector $X$ has density. **Typo:** Given the definition of $S_t$, I don't know what you mean by "$x_n \in S_t$". I have also posted an answer below which only assumes $X$ has density, and then uses a truncation argument (maybe this is what you had in mind in your very first comment ?).

Comment: thank you. Indeed, in that book the result is "iff" with continuity for the distribution. Even for atomic distributions, they have nice formulas in terms of t=0.

Comment: yes indeed. But still I advise checking out their book if possible, they go into depth with many formulas.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Sorry, if possible, would you mind taking a look at this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434736/how-to-get-the-lower-bound-of-the-following-tau? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> **Claim.** *If $X$ has density, then $L(S_p^n,t) \longrightarrow 0$ in the limit $t \to 0^+$.*

Indeed, if $X$ has density, then so does $F(X)$, for any continuous function $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. In particular, for every $w \in \mathbb R^n$, the random variable $X' w$ has density, and hence a continuous CDF.
Let $R$ be a large positive number. By compacity of $S_p^n \times [-R,R]$ and the preceding argument, the function $t \mapsto \underset{w \in S_p^n,\,|u| \le R}{\sup}\mathbb P(|X'w-u| \le t)$ is continuous, and so
$$
\tag{1}
\lim_{t \to 0^+}\sup_{w \in S_p^n}\sup_{|u| \le R}\mathbb P(|X'w-u| \le t) = \sup_{w \in S_p^n,\,|u| \le R}\lim_{t \to 0^+}\mathbb P(|X'w-u| \le t) = 0.
$$

On the other hand, if $|u| \gt R$, then $|X'w-u| \ge ||X'w| - |u|| \ge |u| - |X'w| \gt R-|X'w|$, and so for any $t \ge 0$, one computes
$$
\begin{split}
\sup_{w \in S_p^n}\sup_{|u| \gt R} \mathbb P(|X'w-u| \le t) &\le  \mathbb P(R - |X'w| \le t) \le \sup_{w \in S_p^n} \mathbb P(|X'w| \ge R - t)\\
& \le  \mathbb P(\sup_{w \in S_p^n} |X'w| \ge R - t)\\
&= \mathbb P(\|X\|_q \ge R - t) \longrightarrow 0 \text{ in the limit }R \to \infty.
\end{split}
\tag{2}
$$

In the last step, we have used the fact that the CDF of $\|X\|_q$ is continuous (because $X$ has density and so $\|X\|_q$ does too, by continuity of the $\ell_q$-norm on $\mathbb R^n$). Combining (1) and (2) completes the claim.